# HAProxy health check not working but CURL returns 200 OK

Tags: php, curl, haproxy

I have a HAProxy health check configured with the following backend:

```
backend php_servers
   http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]
   option httpchk get /health
   http-check expect status 200
   server php1 internal_ip:80 check
```

HAProxy doesn't enable the server but when using CURL I receive a 200 OK response.

```
Command: curl -I internal_ip/health
Response:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 01 Dec 2016 20:53:48 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: api.flex-appeal.nl
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-transform
```

Why doesn't HAProxy recognize the servers as "UP"? Seems I can connect just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct HTTP verb is `GET`, not `get`:

```
option httpchk GET /health
```

You can also check/enable the [stats page](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.7/configuration.html#stats%20enable): on the `LastChk` column you will see *why* the check fails. In my case, I get a `501 Not Implemented` response.

I can reproduce it by doing the same request as HAProxy:

```
$ telnet localhost 80
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
get /health HTTP/1.0

HTTP/1.1 501 Not Implemented
Date: Thu, 01 Dec 2016 21:53:09 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.23 (Unix) PHP/7.0.13
[...]
```